# Is there any advantage of using declaration files over sources in typescript?

Tags: typescript, declaration-files

When creating and publishing a library using typescript there are 2 options:

1. Generate declaration files `d.ts` together with the bundled javascript file and then in `package.json` point to it with:

   "types": "./dist/mylib.d.ts"
2. Don't generate the declaration files and point directly to the source code in `package.json` witt:

   "types": "./src/index.ts"

What is the adventage of each one?

Comment: Declarations don't contain code, they should be faster to parse and type check, and with `skipLibCheck` they will not be type checked at all by the compiler when someone uses your lib so again they should be even faster. I would ship with declarations.

Comment: does that happens even if you specify the bundled javascript file as main in `package.json`: something like:

```
"main": "./dist/my-lib-bundled.js",
"types": "./src/index.ts"
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest the following strategy:

### Library Package

In the library package, distribute only the complied JavaScript with the declarations files. This has the advantage of reducing the package size while giving developers the option to use your library with either JavaScript or TypeScript.

### Code Repository

In the code repository for the library, only commit the source files - not the compiled JavaScript nor the declarations files. Put instructions for how to compile the library in your README, and perhaps also a script that will perform the compilation. This will allow other developers to change and use your library after any modifications they make.